# In Verilog, can a "for loop" be of variable size?

Tags: verilog

I will give a small snippet of what I mean:

```
input [31:0] for_terminate;
for(i = 0; i < for_terminate; i = i + 1)
....
```

Clearly, this is a small piece of code, but I think it illustrates my idea.  Is this possible?

Comment: What are you actually trying to implement? Typical mistake for ppl coming from the "classical" programming languages is to transfer common pattern directly (at least that is what I did). But verilog is "bottom up". Means one "plugs circuits" together instead of "feeding a FSM". As already shown by Oldfart, implementation of a loop is possible but basically all the "operations" are done in parallel then. Maybe you actually want to implement it as sequential process flow instead e.g. as FSM. Additional information regarding the usecase would be valuable to improve the answers.

Comment: You're right. It makes no sense. What I am trying to do is have a user definable number of modules. I think I'll need to use flags instead. Like, only if the msb is 1 will the particular module be considered

Comment: basically this is not (really) possible as well at least for "runtime". Only thing you can achieve is having n modules implemented/wired and then enable/disable them depending on the internal state of your device.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you actually ask: can this be synthesized. The answer is NO.

A for loop is unrolled in compile time. (See also [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377657/is-this-matrix-vector-multiplication-function-in-vhdl-parallelized/377667?r=SearchResults&s=1|24.5760#377667) ) As such the start, increment and end value must be known when you compile. This also means it is good practice to limit your for loop range. The following code is legal, can be synthesized, but will not fit in your FPGA or ASIC:

```
for (i=0; i<4294967296; i=i+1)
begin
  // Make some logic
  ...
```

You can make the equivalent with an if:

```
for (i=0; i<MAXIMUM_LOOP; i=i+1)
begin
   if (i<for_terminate)
   begin
      ...
```

The logic for all MAXIMUM_LOOP cases will be generated, but each will have a condition which checks the value of `for_terminate`. Seeing that your `for_terminate` is 32 bits wide, I think you should limit that somewhat.